# selenium slow preformance on realtime Django project

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project which I'm getting posts from couple of websites and show it in the main page of my website but with filter and letting users to search for keywords and see the posts with that keywords.
this is how the code works:

In here with get the customized url of the site with our keyword and city filter

```
def link_gen(city='', Kword='' ):
  # for example.com
  urls =[]
  if Kword != '':
    if city =='':
      url = f'https://www.example.com/search/with{Kword}'
      url = url.strip()
      url = url.replace(" ", "-")
      urls.append(url)
    else:
      url = f'https://www.example.com/search/with{Kword}in{city}'
      url = url.strip()
      url = url.replace(" ", "-")
      urls.append(url)
  else:
    if city != '':
      url = f'https://www.example.com/search/in{city}'
      url = url.strip()
      url = url.replace(" ", "-")
      urls.append(url)
    else: urls.append('none')
  return urls
```

this part is where we crawl for the posts of the target website

```
# function for getting the title, link, icon, desc of all posts
def get_cards(urls):
  data = []

  # for  example.com
  if urls[0] != 'none':
    # we use webdriver to get site with dynamic component and design
    url = urls[0]
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    browser.get(url)
    print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

    jobs = soup.find_all( 'div', class_="job-list-item", limit=3)

    # looping through all the cards  
    for job in jobs :
      # get the title, link, icon, desc  
      title = job.find('a', class_= "title vertical-top display-inline" ).text
      icon  = job.find(tage_name_img)['src']
      link  = job.find('a', class_= "title vertical-top display-inline" )['href']
      date  = job.find('div', class_= "date" ).text
      data.append(dict(
      title = title,
      icon = f'https://www.example.com/{icon}',
      link = f'https://www.example.com/{link}',
      date = date,
      site = 'example'
      ))
    browser.close()
  return data
```

but the problem is for getting the post and dynamic tags on the websites I needed to use selenium I can't use `session.get(url)` because it won't return all the tags
and with selenium it takes for ever to return the posts even though I only crawl 3 posts
but I think webdriver uses a lot of resources.
I ran out of ram when I when I tried to run it locally 
any suggestion would be so much appreciated

Comment: Which part of the code is slow? Put `start = time.time()` before a code block and `print(f'part x: {time.time() - start:.2f}')` after the code block. Do this for many code blocks and substitute x with 1, 2, etc

Comment: thanks for answering @soundwave I'll do it and comeback with result, but i think mostly  it's this part that takes a lot of time to run: 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')` and   `jobs = soup.find_all( 'div', class_="job-list-item", limit=3)`

Comment: Also, how many times is `get_cards(urls)` executed?

Comment: @soundwave after testing each part here is the result : 
the  `get_cards` function takes about 10 to 12 seconds, then I tried to time each block to see which one is taking time , assigning the browser variable with webdriver takes about 4 to 5 secs and `browser.get(url)` takes about 5 to 6 secs and assigning `soup and jobs ` only takes 1.6 to 1.9 seconds, and the other takes below 0.5 seconds, and `get_cards(urls)` executed 4 times (for number of websites that I wanna crawl which rn is 4)

Comment: Ok good, can you move `browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)` outside of the function? Also, notice that `browser.close()` doesn't actually kill the instance, you should use `driver.quit()`

Comment: yeah but where should I put it ? outside of all functions and pass in through as an arg in `get_cards` function? and also if I do that where should I put `driver.quit()`? 
or I can put the browser in my view and then after getting data I can use `driver.quit()`, you think this would help?

Comment: Well you said that `get_cards` is executed 4 times, so the best thing is starting the webdriver before the first execution and quitting after the last execution. If you give me the full code I can try to optimize it in terms of speed

Comment: @soundwave yeah sure! is it okay if I give you github link?

Comment: yyes it is fine

Comment: @soundwave sorry for the late answer, here is the repo of the project  [link](https://github.com/novartis-nk/Post-Job-Crawler)

Comment: ok, can you also give me some values for `Kword` and `city` to put into `https://www.simplyhired.com/search?q={Kword}&l={city}` so that I can test `get_cards` on those urls?

Comment: you can give the Kword any job title and city any city name if it returned nothing most probably is bc there are no jobs in that city OR the city is not well defined 
you can go like Kword = python developer and city = texas or you can also leave the city out